# Rails 3: Restrict a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship: users --< comments >-- products.  However, I only want a product's comment visible to its author.

The route is:

```
resources :products do
  resources :comments
end
```

The query in the Index action of the CommentsController would be something like:

```
# @product loaded in before_filter
@comments = @product.comments.where(:author_id=>current_user) # returns 0 or 1 records
```

I could change the routes to:

```
resources :products do
  resource :comments
end
```

then use the Show action:

```
# @product loaded in before_filter
@comment = @product.comments.where(:author_id=>current_user) # returns 0 or 1 records
```

If there are no comments, this should probably route automatically to the New action, but I haven't been able to get this to work.

Is this a reasonable approach for this user-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a redirect_to in your show-method if there is no comment.

Comment: That worked (in combination with the singular route).  The exact syntax is redirect_to(:action => 'new') and return if @comment.nil?